# wmi remote query: bind source ip or use ip proxy?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, wmi, wmi-query

Here it is a simple example of a WMI connection to a remote host:

```
string FullComputerPathName=@"\\mycomputer\root\cimv2";

ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Password = "some_password";
options.Username = "some_user";

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(FullComputerPathName,options);
scope.Connect();
```

Is there any chance to do one of these options:

1)
use an IP proxy to get to the remote host.
Example(something like this):

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(FullComputerPathName,options);
**scope.ProxyIP = myIPaddress**
scope.Connect();
```

2)
specify a source ip on the WMI connection.
Example(something like this):

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(FullComputerPathName,options);
**scope.Connection.SourceIP = myIPaddress**
scope.Connect();
```

Thanks in advance for any tip!